# Chrome DNS spoofing protections

Tags: security, dns, dhcp, spoofing, access-point

Im running kali Linux 2.0 and am doing DNS spoofing via an evil twin AP.

I have started a dhcp client and configured the hosts file to redirect google.com to my apache2 web server running a very simple webpage that simply displays "hello world"

The problem comes when I try to resolve the address via chrome or firefox. I am able to redirect and display my custom webpage when running on IE, but nothing works on chrome or firefox and I get the message : page not found. It seems that chrome likes to force me to use https://

I'm wondering if anyone knows the security features that come with chrome or firefox that would prevent this sort of attack

thanks!! let me know if I need to provide any info

Answer (score 0):

HSTS might have this effect.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

"HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) is a web security policy mechanism which helps to protect websites against protocol downgrade attacks and cookie hijacking. It allows web servers to declare that web browsers (or other complying user agents) should only interact with it using secure HTTPS connections,[1] and never via the insecure HTTP protocol. HSTS is an IETF standards track protocol and is specified in RFC 6797.
The HSTS Policy[2] is communicated by the server to the user agent via an HTTP response header field named "Strict-Transport-Security". HSTS Policy specifies a period of time during which the user agent should only access the server in a secure fashion."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! THis is really helpful. 

As a followup question: Is there a way for me to use apache2 to make my website https protocol?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider voting it up/marking it as such.

Comment: Re HTTPS on Apache -- sure, Apache support HTTPS, https://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/. You can also put stunnel or socat in front of it. You will need SSL server certificate to make it work. You can generate your own with tinyca2 tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to HSTS requirements of, in your case "google.com".

You can easily "solve" that problem and get proper spoofed DNS redirection setting server to which you are spoofing to SSL Enabled mode.

Then after entering "google.com" in your "attacked" machine instead of seeing not loaded page (as previously nothing responded on 443 port of your server) you will most likely see a failed SSL handshake (unless you'll manage to provide valid certificate for google.com for your server ;-) ).

If you're using standard Ettercap and Apache2 on Kali setting you may find that usefull:
https://hallard.me/enable-ssl-for-apache-server-in-5-minutes/